# Why are gethostbyname and gethostbyaddr considered obsolete?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

The man page `gethostbyname`(3) states that the functions `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr` are obsolete, and that `getaddrinfo`(3) and `getnameinfo`(3) should be used instead. It doesn't, however, explain the reason why the former are obsolete. Can anyone please point me to some resource that explains the matter further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html)

> The `gethostbyaddr()` and `gethostbyname()` functions may return pointers to static data, which may be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of these functions.
>
> The `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` functions are preferred over the `gethostbyaddr()` and `gethostbyname()` functions.

POSIX cautions that `gethostbyaddr()` and`gethostbyname()` may be withdrawn in a future version of the spec. The other reason is that these two functions can't work with IPv6 well,  `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks, the wording on the OpenGroup's website is indeed clearer than my manual page. BTW, do you have any more source about the fact that "the two functions can't work well with IPv6"? I have only found [beej](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html), which says that only `gethostbyname()` doesn't work well with IPv6, but not saying why. (The man page says that the `hostent` structure can accommodate `AF_INET6` data.)